# GRAV custom fields / html blocks / custom theme templates

Tags: html, twig, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin, grav

I'm trying to build a static website using the GRAV CMS. So far, I've been creating ***.html.twig** files and associating a single page to the individual template.

This is how my pages look:

```
{% block header%}
{% include 'partials/bhss-default-header.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

#CONTENT

{% block footer%}
{% include 'partials/bhss-default-footer.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, my purpose is to have an editor creating pages from the admin interface and adding HTML blocks similar to the **custom fields** or **shortcodes** in WordPress. I want this blocks to be filled with text.

I need to mention that my website is built with **Semantic-UI**, so I'm not using any theme provided by GRAV.

How can I replicate this behavior and what choices do I have ? The website is small at this time, so I can remake every page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use editor, you need to build your header and footer as Grav pages in Markdown, not Grav theme's template file in Twig. Example:

```
{% block header%}
{{ pages.find('/my-header').content }}
{% endblock %}

#CONTENT

{% block footer%}
{{ pages.find('/my-footer').content }}
{% endblock %}
```

`my-header` and `my-footer` are 2 pages. You can unpublish these pages to hide them from your menu and forbid direct access to them.